# How to disable authorizations in IBM MQ 7.0

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

How can we disable authorizations on MQ version 7.0.1.3 on windows platform?

I know in version 7.0 you can disable channel authorizations. But I cannot find a way to disable authorizations in 7.0.1.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authorizations on 7.0.1.3 can be disabled by putting environment variable MQSNOAUT=yes on both windows and UNIX. The variable has to be set before creation of queue manager and during the life cycle of queue manager, authorizations cannot be re-enabled.

Below link explains  in detail the use of MQSNOAUT:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc%2Ffa13260_.htm

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

MQSC command `ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)` will disable channel authorizations in MQ v7.5 too.

BTW: Are you sure MQ version is 8.1? The last released version of MQ is v7.5.

EDIT:

Channel authorization feature was introduced in MQ v7.1. So that feature not available in MQ v701x and hence can't disable.

Comment: Corrected the version number in question. Apologies for incorrect question.

Comment: Problem is that my program connects to 7.0.1.3 Queue manager returns error 2035 which is MQRC_NOT_AUTORIZED. If the authorizations are introduced in 7.1, what can be causing the MQ to return the error?

Comment: That is because the user id with which your client application is connecting to remote v7013 queue manager does not exist or is not part of 'mqm' group on the machine where v7013 queue manager is running.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to disbale authorization or how to allow unknown user name ? I have enabled debug trace on the queue manage and it looks like that mq is unable to identify the user for my process that is putting messages on the queue. The principal is getting resolved to a number '1717' which does not exist anywhere. Both client and MQ and on the same machine. I am assuming that 1717 is probably something analogous to 'unknown'. Is there a way to allow this unknown users to put messages on the queue? By the way same process is able to read messages from the queue.

Comment: The reason I am getting confused about authorizations is that at queue manager level I am seeing options to set object authorities, manage/create authorities & manage authority records using MQ explorer in version 7.0.1.3. Are these authorizations different from channel authorizations?

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you are getting 2035 error, which makes you think that channel authentication is turned on for you.

As explained by Shashi, CHLAUTH came only, MQ7.1 onwards and its actual purpose is to block all admin access through SVRCONN channels by default(All System.* channels are blocked).

Check [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/blocked_by_chlauth_why?lang=en) for more details.

But, `user authentication was always there`.

> Check the user id with which you are trying to connect.

That **user id must have access** to the MQ object. In other words, user id must be added in the **user-group** which has access to the MQ objects. For eg, user ids added to **`"mqm"`** group, will have admin permissions to the MQ objects.

Steps to add a user id in a user group will vary from OS to OS. Mention your OS in the question.

Also, you can try to give authorizations to your user using **setmqaut** command.
[**Here**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa15980_.htm) is the usage of the command.

Comment: The output from my dspmqver is: Name: Websphere MQ, Version: 7.0.1.3, CMVC level: p701-103-100818, BuildType: IKAP - (Production).The reason I am getting confused about authorizations is that at queue manager level I am seeing options to set object authorities, manage/create authorities & manage authority records using MQ explorer in version 7.0.1.3. Are these authorizations different from channel authorizations?

Comment: I have tried setting authorizations using setmqaut command. The issue is that the process putting message to MQ is connecting without credentials or at least MQ is unable to resolve the process user resulting in MQ not being able to determine the authorities. Is there any way to authorize everyone or authorize unknowns? The platform in question is Windows server 2008.

Comment: Check the MCA USER property of the channel. Try setting it to "mqm". Are you trying to connect via client app or MQ explorer?

Comment: Actually I have a C++ tuxedo app that uses MQAdapter to connect to MQ. I shall try setting the property to above.

Comment: Your App would be sending a user id. Few applications send your current user id, with which your are logged in to the machine. Check what user id is being sent, and check if that has access to the MQ objects.

Comment: I checked and as per trace logs, the MQ is unable to determine the user id. As I stated the Principal is getting resolved to 1717 which is not making any sense in current setup because there is no user with id either on the machine or the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The user ID 'xxxxx' and its password were checked because the queue manager connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication information (AUTHINFO) object named 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS' with CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL). &P This message accompanies a previous error to  clarify the reason for the user ID and password check.

So changed SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS and SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWLDAP in Authentication Information to have Username+password - "none" for check locally bound connections and "none" for check client connections.

Note : Changes are reflected only after restart of queue manager.

Comment: Anand, note the question asked was about a specific version of MQ (7.0).  CONNAUTH was not introduced until MQ v8.0 so your answer would not apply to this question.  Try searching for questions about CONNAUTH and DISABLE.  One search that came up with a few is "[ibm-mq] CONNAUTH DISABLE".  This answer is not for this question and should be deleted.

Comment: You can delete your answer by selecting the link ***delete*** link under the answer text.